# Merging updated code from parallel Subversion repository

Tags: svn, merge, repository

I was wondering what steps people generally take when it comes to merging a live (continually updated) SVN respository with an offline one (updated less often), as an example, take my scenario:

A while ago I downloaded the BugTracker.NET system when it was at version 3.2.3. I've subsequently make some enhancements to the code for our business. We develop these under source control using SVN. Meanwhile of course, the core BugTracker.NET code has continued to be developed. I basically want all of the updates from the BugTracker.NET SourceForge repository (which I believe is also SVN) merged across into my own in-house repository.

What, in your opinion, is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, subversion is a suboptimal choice for such a workflow, try a distributed version control system like GIT, Bazaar, etc

if you have to stay on subversion, make use of the [vendor-branch-pattern](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html):

- import the new version into a
  separate branch
- merge the diff between V3.2.3 and the new version into your current trunk (you need to
  use the  **--ignore-ancestry** option)